# Bind textbox text to disk path of xml file

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding

I have a window set up that shows the data in an xml file and allows the user to change it, save, etc.  I have pretty much evertything set up except that I would like to have a textbox or textblock that shows the file path of the current file that the user is working with.

I have an XmlDataProvider set up called 'xmlData' and I have the text binding as follows:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Source, Source={StaticResource xmlData}}"
```

I have also tried the datacontext to the static resource above and both just give me a blank textbox even though I know there is an xml file in the data provider (I can write to it).  Am I missing something or can this not be done this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well I figured something out that works but it's not what I wanted.  I ended up going 'old school' with it.  I put a standard property on my form in the code behind with a backing variable and get/set methods.  In the set method I just set the text property to the same value as the backing variable.

I'm waiting to mark this as the answer to see if someone has a better solution.

--What I tried--

After the above answer/conversation I tried sticking a converter in that simply returned the value back so that I could break into it in the debugger and see what was being passed to the converter.  No matter what I did I couldn't get it to hit the breakpoint so it seems like it wasn't even getting to the converter for some reason.

I then tried to define a dependency property on the code behind of the form itself and a standard property as a wrapper (where the get and set just use the GetValue and SetValue on the dependency property) and bind the textbox text to that using relativesource and findancestor.  Basically I bound the text to that property of the form.  Then I changed the property using the wrapper in code behind whenever the user browsed for a new file.  This worked on the load up, but whenever I set the value in code it didn't update the text in the textbox.  I even set the binding tracing to high using diagnostics; I saw that it found the form and said it bound to the value, etc. but whenever I hit the browse method and change the path I get no output and no change in the text.

Like I said, what I have is working and it's reasonable I guess, but if anyone can add insight as to why this wouldn't work I would be very interested to know.  I am fairly new to WPF so I want to learn to do these things right...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `XmlDataProvider.Source` is a `Uri` not a string.  So you will want to do something like:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Source.AbsolutePath, Source={StaticResource xmlData}}"
```

Absolute path isn't going to give you something like: `C:\My documents\test.xml` however, it's more likely to be something like: `file://c:/my documents/test.xml`.  So you'll need to find a good way to manipulate the source `Uri` to get what you want.

One thing you could do is use a [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to parse it and return what you want.

It looks like `Uri.LocalPath` might also give you what you want, but I'm not 100% sure without testing it.

Comment: Hmmm.  That makes sense but I changed it to both exactly what you have there as well as 'Source.LocalPath' and I still get nothing.  I'll look into it more with converters to see if I can figure out what's happening...

Comment: None...  There are two related to a treeview on the form but none related to that text box or the data provider or anything like that...